# Button Click - Play a Sound or Nav to a Page?

Tags: android

First time poster. Im totally new to Android but I have manged to dreate a UI with two buttons. Im now attempting to find out how to hook up Button 1 to a WAV file and Button 2 to go to a second page. 
Could any body please provide or link to an "easy" explanation on how to play a WAV file when clicking a button and how to open a new page when clicking the second button?
Ive found examples on the web (for the sound) but they fail to describe the full content needed such as other system "coms" etc.
Thanks all.

Comment: Is there a 'hard' example you've been looking at that we could use as the base?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've asked a general question, so the best I can do is give you a general response. For the playing sound, I'd look at the documentation that android provides for the [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) class. For launching another page, that's as simple as creating a new [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) with the activity you want to open. You'd engage both of these things by setting an [OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29) for your buttons.

Comment: Hi Guys,Here is the details as promised. I included the two button details and the contents of the.java file. i would very much appreciate any pointers as to how to wire up a WAv file and a new page on the button clicks. Also, when I tried to add a new forder under 'res' named 'Audio', the project would not compile. All feed back appreciated.

Comment: `Button 2 (click to play WAV file)
======================
<ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/clicker" 
                android:background="@null"
                />`

Comment: `Button 1 ( click to navigate to new page)
===========================
<ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/train_butt" 
                android:background="@null"           
                />`

Comment: `package com.MyTest.MyTestActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyTestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}`